# How do I present application with additional server mode on macOS to customer

Tags: macos, installation

I have a desktop application that I successfully package and install on macOS using *dmgcanvas*. The user simply drags the icon into Applications to install and then run by clicking on the Application Icon in Applications.

My problem is whereas the software was previously a Desktop only application it now has a new mode whereby it runs as a server, and can then be controlled via a web browser. On Windows, I would simply create another .exe file with the option set to run as server and put this in the installation folder, so the user would just run MyApp.exe or MyAppServer.exe

But in macOS I can not see how to do the equivalent thing since there is just one folder Myapp.app containing the installation and clicking on Myapp.app runs the application, so where do I put MyAppServer?

Of course, the user could right-click on MyApp.app and run *Show Package Contents* and then navigate to a subfolder such as *bin* containing a cmdline version that runs in server mode. But how is the user supposed to know how to do that, I want an easy way for the user to run MyAppServer?

Comment: Could be missing something but seems you want to create a Daemons ? Maybe have a choice in the app to enable/disable the daemon version. 
 https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html

Comment: @KrisRice not really in the sense that it is not something they would want to run all the time, sometime they would want to run in Desktop mode, and sometimes in Server mode. Lets simplify, if my application contained two Desktop tools how would user start them both ?

Comment: Gotcha. Did you think about a menu bar item that has 2 drop menu items. Start Server, Open Desktop ?

Comment: You mean start MyApp, and then you can choose whether to run in server or desktop mode, I have thought of that and may do  that. However that would only work if user is sat infront of Mac with screen, not suitable if connecting remotely without screen. But I still feel there must be a more generic way to deal with this situation.

Comment: Okay, this looks like a hack, but why not just make a `MyAppServer.app` package with all relevant data symlinked (or hardlinked) from the corresponding data in `MyApp.app`? The main executable file should be the only difference between those two versions.

Comment: Im really looking to see what is the correct way to do this, raher than a hack, what do others do ?

Comment: You could create an AppleScript that launches your app in "server" mode. AppleScript can be saved as applications (.app) which you could ship side-by-side with your main bundle.

Comment: @TheNextman - if I did this would I need two .dmg, or can one .dmg be expanded into two .apps

Comment: A .dmg is just a disk image, you can ship whatever you like. However I haven't used dmgcanvas.

Comment: That said, I don't think this is the right way to go. Provide a single bundle. Allow the user to start minimised / minimise it down to a NSStatusItem (see `NSApplicationActivationPolicy`). This way they can still stop or quit when you have no UI visible. Your "server" will need to be a CLI app embedded in the bundle, or your users "without screen" will not be able to start it.

Comment: My app can already be run as cmdline, in fact the only different between MyApp and MyAppServer would be that MyAppServer runs MyApp but with the -r option, all Im trying to do really is let user run MyApp but with -r enabled without them having to excplicity open Terminal and run Myapp -r

Comment: @PaulTaylor well, then the problem boils down to distributing a file named e.g. `MyAppServer.command` along with your app. There you need to provide a shell command to make your app run in server mode.

Comment: Well yes,. but its not clear where to put it.

Comment: @PaulTaylor, see if my answer helps you achieve what you want

Answer (score 0):

Its hard for find documentation of how things exactly work on MacOS. But below is a good article

https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/shell-script-mac-apps

> The internal folder structure may vary between apps, but you can be sure that every Mac app will have a Contents folder with a MacOS subfolder in it. Inside the MacOS directory, there’s an extension-less file with the exact same name as the app itself. This file can be anything really, but in its simplest form it’s a shell script. As it turns out, this folder/file structure is all it takes to create a functional app!

They have a simple script to automate the whole process

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

APPNAME=${2:-$(basename "${1}" '.sh')};
DIR="${APPNAME}.app/Contents/MacOS";

if [ -a "${APPNAME}.app" ]; then
    echo "${PWD}/${APPNAME}.app already exists :(";
    exit 1;
fi;

mkdir -p "${DIR}";
cp "${1}" "${DIR}/${APPNAME}";
chmod +x "${DIR}/${APPNAME}";

echo "${PWD}/$APPNAME.app";
```

So what I would do is that, instead of having my apps binary directly, I will have a Shell Script and the Binary in the same folder. This shell script will check if the `AppName Server.app` already exists or not, if not, it will create the folder and put a script which then calls your original app with `-r` flag.

And then I would just run the actual app with the pass arguments that were passed to the script

Is this the best approach? Not sure about that, I could not find a way where a app has multiple Icons in but just one folder. In this case the Server option will not exists on first installation of the app, but after the first run of the app. You could even ask the user if they really want an additional icon for the app or not.

Comment: Its a possibility, I havent fully digested your answer yet but since bounty period is nearly over and this answer is certainly helpful I award you the bounty.